# How to close hamburger nav on click of the <a> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As the title states, I am wanting my hamburger navbar to close when I click on the  tags I have tried many ways for the last couple hours but am unable to solve my problem?

I Have tried setting the hide() property with jquery but no luck think it may be because i am pretty new to JS and am just wanting to get my website finished.

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
const mobileContent = document.querySelector(".mobile-content");
const mobileItem = document.querySelector(".mobile-item");
const mobileItems = document.querySelectorAll(".mobile-items");


// Set Initial State Of Menu
let showMenu = false;
menuBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);
function toggleMenu() {
  if (!showMenu) {
    menuBtn.classList.add("close");
    mobileContent.classList.add("show");
    mobileItem.classList.add("show");
    mobileItems.forEach(item => item.classList.add("show"));
    
    
 // Set Menu State
    showMenu = true;
  } else {
    menuBtn.classList.remove("close");
    mobileContent.classList.remove("show");
    mobileItem.classList.remove("show");
    mobileItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove("show"));
    // Set Menu State
    showMenu = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.mobile-nav {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
.mobile-nav .menu-btn {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mobile-nav .menu-btn .btn-line {
  width: 28px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  background: #333;
}

.mobile-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.mobile-content.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
.mobile-content .mobile-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: blue;
  list-style: none;
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}
.mobile-content .mobile-link {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Mobile Nav -->
     <div class="mobile-nav">
       <div class="menu-btn">
         <div class="btn-line"></div>
         <div class="btn-line"></div>
         <div class="btn-line"></div>
       </div>
       <a href="#home"><h2>MATTY</h2></a>
       <nav class="mobile-content">
         <ul class="mobile-item">
           <li class="mobile-items">
             <a href="#about-me" class="mobile-link">
               ABOUT
             </a>
           </li>
           <li class="mobile-items">
             <a href="#the-portfolio" class="mobile-link">
               PORTFOLIO
             </a>
           </li>
           <li class="mobile-items">
             <a href="#" class="mobile-link">
               BLOG
             </a>
           </li>
           <li class="mobile-items">
             <a href="#contact-me" class="mobile-link">
               CONTACT
             </a>
           </li>
         </ul>
       </nav>
       </div>
```

Comment: Your snippet uses Sass. Be aware that that's not natively supported by Stack Snippets… though maybe there's a setting. I'll check.

Comment: I didn't know that I am pretty new here does that mean I should retype code into CSS to put on here next time?

Comment: It means that you should edit your question _now_ so that your example works, otherwise people won't be able to use it.

Comment: As per @wizzwizz4 just copy the compiled CSS from browser and use that here. Note in the answer I just ripped it out for now.

Comment: @MPB You've got an answer to your question, but it'd be great if you could still edit your question to make it better. That way, you'll make it better for the next person to come along with this issue. If the person who had this issue before you had done this, you'd have found the issue sooner.

Comment: Hope okay to message you again I have created an animation with the hamburger icon so when clicked it turns into an X what would be the best way to activate this preferably adding onto the javascript u suggested to me is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove some of your CSS as it was not working in the snippet.

Recommend you use `element.classList.toggle()` as below.

Note how much simpler the code becomes.

EDIT: Clicking any `a` tag will now close menu

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if(e.target.matches('.menu-btn') 
  || e.target.matches('.btn-line')
  || e.target.matches('a')) {
    toggleMenu();
  }
});

function toggleMenu() {
  document.querySelector('.mobile-content').classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
.btn-line {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.mobile-nav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.mobile-content {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Mobile Nav -->
<div class="mobile-nav">
  <div class="menu-btn">
    <span class="btn-line"></span>
    <span class="btn-line"></span>
    <span class="btn-line"></span>
  </div>
  <a href="#home">
    <h2>MATTY</h2>
  </a>
  <nav class="mobile-content hide">
    <ul class="mobile-item">
      <li class="mobile-items">
        <a href="#about-me" class="mobile-link">
               ABOUT
             </a>
      </li>
      <li class="mobile-items">
        <a href="#the-portfolio" class="mobile-link">
               PORTFOLIO
             </a>
      </li>
      <li class="mobile-items">
        <a href="#" class="mobile-link">
               BLOG
             </a>
      </li>
      <li class="mobile-items">
        <a href="#contact-me" class="mobile-link">
               CONTACT
             </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that looks a lot more cleaner now will now edit in my project the reason i used that JS i had originally is because i am still in the process of learning js a bit more better am just needing the <a> tags to close when clicked

Comment: Ok, the `Matty` link? Or all of them?

Comment: Should be ok now.

Comment: The code u provided did not work on my project the navbar does not open with that code on my page.

and on all the links so when I click the <a> tag is closes the navbar and goes to the section of my page

Comment: Did you see I added a new `CSS` class called `hide`. Also I removed the `hidden` from your existing `CSS`. You will need to do that also. Then add the class `hide` to you element.

Comment: Just done and still no luck the hamburger is not opening up when I click the icon now?

Comment: Can you update the code in your question and we can look. Remember to use compiled CSS.

Comment: I managed to get it working it turns out the rest of my code was causing it to break so will just have to re-add all the styling thank you for your help much appreciated!

Comment: No problem, happy coding!!

Comment: Thank you-you too!

Answer (score 0):

@MPB A good way to dabble into some simple JQuery language is a way to fix your problem. A quick and easy way to make a good Hamburger Navigation menue is with the `toggleClass();` function in JQuery. Just make a `@keyframes-animation` within an un-set class and `toggleClass();` will switch between the two seamlessly. I do this all the time, comment if you'd like me to forward the code to you for you to use.